# WPF custom control virtualization

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm implementing my own control based on `Grid` (**not** `DataGrid`). This control displays `DataTable` contents and supports column-, row- and elementwise selection (the reason for not using `DataGrid` is complexity of such manipulations). It gets filled with elements like this:

```
private void DrawGrid(DataTable table)
{
    // grdMain stays for the grid itslef
    grdMain.RowDefinitions.Clear();
    grdMain.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
    var padding = new Thickness(5, 2, 5, 2);

    for (int colNumber = 0; colNumber <= table.Columns.Count; colNumber++)
    {
        //Here comes logic for ColumnDefinitions addition
    }

    //First row is for table header
    grdMain.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
    //Main loop where the whole stuff gets added into the table
    for (int rowNumber = 1; rowNumber <= table.Rows.Count; rowNumber++)
    {
        grdMain.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        // First column is for row numbers
        for (int colNumber = 1; colNumber <= table.Columns.Count; colNumber++)
        {
            //grdMain.Children.Add(CreateHeaderTextBlock(rowNumber.ToString(), 0, rowNumber, false));
            //grdMain.Children.Add(CreateColumnHeaderRectangle(0, rowNumber));
            var cellTextBlock = new TextBlock()
            {
                Text = table.Rows[rowNumber - 1][colNumber - 1].ToString(),
                Padding = padding
            };

            grdMain.Children.Add(cellTextBlock);
            cellTextBlock.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, rowNumber);
            cellTextBlock.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, colNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Code is pretty trivial, but what it lacks is elements virtualization. For a 1000x10 table it takes more than 3 seconds to render and the bottleneck is layout.

Any ideas on how can the virtualization be implemented? The `grdMain` grid lies in a `ScrollViewer`, which allows this grid to be scrollable. Theoretically I could load new elements and add them on scrolling, but I'm not sure if the scrollbars will work correctly.

**UPD:** The `DataTable` that is passed as a parameter is nothing but `BindableProperty`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(DataTable), typeof(TableSelector),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new DataTable(), OnItemsSourceChanged));

public DataTable ItemsSource
{
    get => (DataTable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
    set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
}
```

The callback `OnItemsSourceChanged` method calls `DrawGrid` in order to re-render the table.

Comment: Could you explain why you are not using DataBinding? This code creates controls and this will cost a lot of time.

Comment: Grid does not support DataBinding

Comment: Tag is WPF so you should use binding. If it is you custom control, implement them. It is not that hard. Here is example how to create them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview . You will avoid a lot of problems in the future.

Comment: The given `DataTable` parameter is a property to bind to. The method I wrote fills the table with the data given to a `BindableProperty`

Comment: I mean it would be better to write code relaited to view in XAML like grid, columnDefinitions an so on (not in backend) and bind there items that you want to show from backend. Or it winforms development that does not use advantages from WPF

Comment: As for you problem - i would say you call DrawGrid on propertyChanged event, is it right? If yes, then on every collection change your hole view will be rewritten

Comment: Yes, that't the idea. If you change the data source, it should be reflected on the UI

Comment: I mean if you want to add three items and use Add(), it will rewrite 3 times, if you will use AddRange() - just once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209052/discussion-between-arli-chokoev-and-sasha).

Comment: This should not at all be based on Grid. Use ItemsControl, Selector or ListBox as a base class.

Comment: @ArliChokoev, "the reason for not using DataGrid is complexity of such manipulations" - IMO, it is still simpler to customize DG than to create something similar from scratch. Disable headers, change ControlTemplate of DataGridCell to TextBlock and you are already close